# Почему нельзя в заголовочном файле определить функцию?

Tags: c++, qt, ооп

Класс, создающийся при создании формы в Qt. Почему я не могу внутри класса определить функцию? При такой записи я получаю ошибку `invalid use of incomplete type 'class Ui::EnterWindow'`

```
namespace Ui {
class EnterWindow;
}

class EnterWindow : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit EnterWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~EnterWindow();
    QString getLogin() {
        return ui->label->text();
    }

private:
    Ui::EnterWindow *ui;
};
```

Если я запишу функций в таком виде

```
QString getLogin();
```

И в .cpp файле определю, то всё будет нормально.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что `invalid use of incomplete type 'class Ui::EnterWindow'`.

Т.е. в данном месте **определение** класса `Ui::EnterWindow` недоступно (хедер с ним включается позже и только в *.cpp файл).

На то, чтобы не включать лишнее в хедр, есть несколько причин и практически все они достаточно мелкие, рекомендательные и субъективные (большинство из них продиктованы категориями «грязно» и/или «плохая практика»), в частности вот на вскидку некоторые из них:

1. Достаточно общепринятый тезис: «полагаться на то что хедр Foo включает Bar (в модуле Baz) — плохая практика». А включение всего в хедр её поощряет.
2. Загрязняется пространство имён при компиляции других модулей.
3. Как следствие значительно увеличивается время компиляции и немного вероятность ошибок.
4. Включать *всё* в хедеры не возможно в случае циклических зависимостей.
5. Предоставлять пользователю интерфейс, который не должен представлять для него интереса — также плохая практика.

Comment: Автоматически включение header 'ui_enterwindow.h' записывается в *.cpp файле, можно ли его включение перенести в файл 'enterwindow.h'?

Comment: @МишаковМаксим, можно, но веских оснований для этого ИМХО нет, а это всё же относительно грязноватый подход..

Comment: а Вы случайно не знаете, с чем связано включение ui в *.cpp файле, а не в *.h? Я как-то стараюсь всё включать в хедере, а в *.cpp только хедер, потому что мне казалось, что так "правильно"

Comment: @МишаковМаксим, добавил в ответ.